# Using sphinx with multiple mysql tables to replace fulltext and optimize SELECT, WHERE, UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

Currently, I'm using mysql for many aspects of my project. I have multiple tables. They total up to 7 and are titled url, text, documents, d_text, members, connections, and permissions. I query  the members(member_id, login, password), connections(manages relationships), and permissions (manages what documents people can see) tables together alot and frequently use the SELECT, WHERE, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE clauses. These three tables are fairly small and brief, so I was wondering, if the row count gets to enormous amounts (millions), would using sphinxse or indexing in sphinx be considered here? These tables use key values to reference each other.

My second question is concerning the use of sphinxse (mysql storage engine) vs sphinx. Im going to be using sphinx to index the url table and documents table (both will index/search through the title column, so two seperate indexes will be created). Is the performance of sphinxse the same as sphinx api?

Comment: Sphinx is a full text search engine, so using it for logins, passwords, permissions etc not only will not help, but can in fact cause some unexpected results.

Comment: yes I know, but i was referring to the sphinx storage engine not the actual search

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx is a full text search engine, so using it for logins, passwords, permissions etc not only will not help, but can in fact cause some unexpected results.

Sphinx Storage Engine is not a storage engine! It does not store any data. It's just a way to easily embed Sphinx search engine into MySQL using it's pluggable storage engine API

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.1/sphinxse-overview.html

Comment: ohh I see. Thank you!. Is the performance of the sphinxse the same as the sphinx api?

Comment: Should be. It's the same engine, just accessed differently.